# Nginx redirect except my IP address

Tags: nginx

All I'm trying to do it redirect all users, apart from my ip address, to a "site down" page using the following

```
 location / {
   rewrite (.*) /sitedown.php redirect;
    allow 94.12.147.139;
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires 30d;
}
```

It redirects fine but won't allow my IP to access the site either. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work:

```
location / {
  #this is the allow/deny/redirect bit
  allow 94.12.147.139;
  deny all;
  error_page 403 sitedown.php;  

  #regular site config when not denied
  index index.html index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
  expires 30d; 
}

location /sitedown.php {allow all;}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
 location / {

    if($remote_addr != Your Ip) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/sitedown.php;
    }

    index index.html index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;

    expires 30d;

}
```